# Eye tracker in oculus

Tags: oculus

I'm currently trying to work out how to find the gaze position of an eye viewed through an oculus. It would be very helpful if someone could help me with this. The image below illustrates my setup. The black rectangle is the Eye tracker which I fitted inside the oculus, the purple line is the oculus screen and the blue line is the curvature of the eye viewed from top. At the moment I can calculate the `gaze_angle` and the `viewing_distance` through the Viewpoint application. I need help in using this information to find the actual `x_gaze` position marked on the picture.

[image]

Comment: Howv would you calibrate the system? The size of the sphere is unknown. Wouldnt it be easier to bake the coordinate taking into calibration and use that as a lookup map. Other than that its just vector operalions.

Comment: So does this only track a very limited range of eye movements? Consider the eye pointing to the left of the left most red line - the viewing distance line cuts through the eye at two points, and the eye tracker presumably cannot see through the eye.

Comment: Also it would be useful to know - do you know the position/angle of the eye tracker relative to the eye and/or do you know the position of the screen relative to the eye (you'd have to fix the Rift at a certain distance away from the user, also most people have their eyes positioned differently with respect to the mount)?